# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++

I have been having an issue with a Binary Search Tree that I am making for a larger project.

There is a node:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
struct Node
{
public:
    Key key;
    vector<Value> value;
    Node* leftNode;
    Node* rightNode;

    Node(Key k, Value v)
    {
        key = k;
        value.push_back(v);
    }
};
```

These nodes are being stored into the BST.

The error occurs in the Insertion function of the BST:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
void BinarySearchTree<Key, Value>::insert(const Key &key, const Value &value)
{
    insert(root, key, value);
}


template <class Key, class Value>
void BinarySearchTree<Key, Value>::insert(Node<Key, Value> *&node, const Key &key, const Value &value)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        node = new Node<Key, Value>(key, value);

    // Error occurs here.
    else if (node->key == key)
        node->value.push_back(value);

    else if (key < node->key)
        insert(node->leftNode, key, value);
    else
        insert(node->rightNode, key, value);
}
```

The first node is inserted into the tree without issue, however the second Insertion call throws the error.

Any help in putting me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: Have you tried running your code with a memory tool like Valgrind or clang Memory/Address Sanitizer?

Comment: You might want to initialize leftNode and rightNode to nullptr.

Comment: If you are making a large project it is better not to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: If this is for a larger project, and not an academic exercise, you may want to use `std::map`.

Comment: This is a problem with an uninitialised pointer, the value of 0xCDCDCDCD is the give away. I would add `leftNode = rightNode = nullptr;` to your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert code seems to assume that `Node::leftNode` and `Node::rightNode` are initialised to `nullptr` but your constructor doesn't ensure that. Try this

```
Node(Key k, Value v)
{
    key = k;
    value.push_back(v);
    leftNode = rightNode = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thank you. I can't believe that I overlooked that

Comment: A good reason to compile with all warnings turned on - most compilers could catch this!

Comment: BTW: heap memory is initialized with `0xCDCDCDCD` in debug builds in Visual Studio. Deleted memory is initialized with `0xDDDDDDDD`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't initialising `leftNode` or `rightNode`. Raw pointer values are not value-initialised if there is no member initialiser for them. `std::unique_ptr`s are default constructed equal to `nullptr`

There also doesn't seem to be any cleanup of `Node`s

```
template <class Key, class Value>
struct Node
{
public:
    Key key;
    std::vector<Value> value;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> leftNode;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> rightNode;

    Node(Key k, Value v)
     : key(k), value({v})
    { }
};
```